# strVar.at(index) vs. strVar[index]

Tags: c++

What is the difference between

```
 strVar.at(index) && strVar[index]
```

?

My project requires me to convert a long number to a string and I'd like to use one of these
to analyze the new string. Also, would it be better to do

```
typedef string num;
```

or should I use the .c_str() command?

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::at(size_t index)` throws an exception of `index` is out of bounds.  `operator[]` doesn't.